# Spring move code from controller to service

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, service, controller

I'm new to spring and will like move my working code from the controller to the service for best practice, but now I get a:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/xls] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause java.lang.NullPointerException
```

MainController.java

```
public class MainController {
  private ListServiceImpl listServiceImpl;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public ModelAndView upload(@RequestParam("myfile") MultipartFile myFile)  throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = myFile.getInputStream();
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("list");
    model.addObject("list", listServiceImpl.getList(inputStream) );
  return model; 
}
```

ListServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class ListServiceImpl implements ListService {
  @Override
  public List<UserAndSum> getList(InputStream inputStream) {
  List <UserAndSum> list25plus25 = new ArrayList<UserAndSum>();
  Workbook workBook = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputStream);
  ..............
  list25plus25 .add(new UserAndSum(previousUser, sum));
return list25plus25;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`listServiceImpl` is never initiated or wired.

Because of that you must get a `NullPointerException` in this line of your `MainController` class:

```
model.addObject("list", listServiceImpl.getList(inputStream) );
```

If you want to manage this by Spring you have to add the `@Autowire` annotation.

By the way. If you have interfaces use them:

```
@Autowired
private ListService listService; //refers to the interface
```

Answer (score 0):

add `@Autowire` to `ListService`, and then use it.

```
@Autowire
private ListService listService;

listService.getList(inputStream)
```

If you are using XML based configuration use,

```
listService = context.getBean("listService");  // listService is your bean name
```

Comment: Thanks, so if I didn't want to use the autowire what have I had to add to the config?

Comment: then use new ListServiceImpl();

Comment: @user2598571 create `bean` in your configuration file and using `getBean()` you can access you r service class instance, I have edited my answer

Comment: @StefanBeike If you are using spring never use `new` operator.

Comment: I understood the comment wrong. I thought he mean without spring.